# How to get Spotlight to default to Internet search?

Tags: ios, spotlight, macos

Spotlight default to open web browser and search Internet for [string].

> Command Space [string] [Enter]

How can I do this?

- browser choice irrelevant
- search engine choice irrelevant
- keystrokes in between [string] and [Enter] preferably zero, else preferably always the same post-[string] pattern.

2013 Macbook Pro Retina OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Comment: If you look for customization, get Alfred for OS X http://www.alfredapp.com/

Comment: Sir, I must say, this Alfred is brilliant. Thank you!